# Extracting data out of text from an API with bash

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I have a challenge, but I don't find any information, including here, about the command *jq*. I had tried *curl* to access the page with a json application API. So I use | to run both, but it always show a error.

```
curl -s "https://ip-api.com/#105.154.81.106" |  jq '.'
```

After all, I had read that '.' comes every content, but the only thing that return is:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
```

Comment: Use English on stackoverflow.com, Portuguese on [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: The error implies that the output from curl (connecting to that specific web page) is not really JSON. Perhaps you need to send a `Content-Type: application/json` header?

Comment: Indeed, it's **not** valid JSON when I request it myself; it has a bunch of escape sequences in it, and still has them when the header is changed to request real JSON output. See all the `ESC[39m`s in `curl -s "https://ip-api.com/#105.154.81.106" | less`. (And that's before we get into other issues; the return specifies `SSL unavailable for this endpoint`, and if we switch from https to http, it *still* has the extra escape sequences, and also is returning its result as `text/plain`).

Comment: ...is this maybe color codes they're trying to insert? Figure out how to turn those off.

Comment: Consider `curl -s blah | ansifilter | jq .` to strip out the escape sequences. [Ansifilter](https://gitlab.com/saalen/ansifilter) is almost as useful as jq ;)

Comment: ...though I'd certainly also hope that the remote API would have a toggle for them on the server side, rather than needing to strip them out on the client.

Comment: adding a content-type header doesn't change the result -- the server is actually returning a 403: Forbidden that looks like JSON, but is actually JSON corrupted by escape sequences. OP has two choices that I can see: Register for an account for the API, or escape the ansi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct endpoint for JSON, according to the [API docs](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json):

```
http://ip-api.com/json
```

So you can try this (non-https):

```
curl -s http://ip-api.com/json/105.154.81.106 |  jq '.'
```

Also stated in the docs:

```
Human usage

You can call ip-api.com, without /json/, from cURL, Wget and other CLI HTTP clients and get colourized, pretty printed JSON
```

Comment: Excelent solution! Thanks you!!

Answer (score 0):

An unauthenticated request against https://ip-api.com/#105.154.81.106 using a user agent like a browser gives a nice webpage with content. A similar request using a commandline client like curl or wget...

```
$ curl -s --dump-header headers "https://ip-api.com/#105.154.81.106" > output
```

You can examine the output and headers in depth.

```
$ cat output 
{
  "status" : "fail",
  "message": "SSL unavailable for this endpoint, order a key at https://members.ip-api.com/"
}
```

It looks like JSON, but it is colored in my terminal.

```
$ cat -e output 
^[[39m{$
  ^[[96m"status"^[[39m : ^[[92m"fail"^[[39m,$
  ^[[96m"message"^[[39m: ^[[92m"SSL unavailable for this endpoint, order a key at https://members.ip-api.com/"^[[39m$
}$
```

There are ansi escape sequences. Let's see if the headers are revealing:

```
$ cat headers
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Wed, 25 Mar 2020 18:06:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 163
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Ttl: 47
X-Rl: 42
```

Well, the Content-Type is plain text, not json, so it's not *wrong*, exactly, but it is surprising. More interesting, though, is that we got a *403*. That message *order a key at [https://members.ip-api.com/](https://members.ip-api.com/_)* is the real meat, though.

Clearly, the intent here is that you should get a key and make an *authenticated* request against the API.

You can clear the ansi sequences using a tool like [ansifilter](https://gitlab.com/saalen/ansifilter)

```
$ ansifilter output | jq -r .message
SSL unavailable for this endpoint, order a key at https://members.ip-api.com/
```

But there are no guarantees that this API will continue to "work" this way in the future.